# Parse.Object.fetchAll with "include" set?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse's JS SDK and I'd like to do the following:

I have an array of objects. I'd like to issue a single query to both fetch the data for these objects, including data for a nested property of the objects. What I'd like to do is akin to the following (which doesn't appear to work):

```
var parents = myInstance.get('parents');
var query = new Parse.Query('ParentClass');

// Below, set query condition to only fetch data for objects 
// found in "parents."
query.containedIn('objectId', idsForArray(parents));

query.include('child'); // Include data for child class

query.find().then(function(results) {
  for result in results {
    result.get('child'); // child data should be fetched
  }
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. I think you should rephrase your question as well as the code to make it more clear.

Comment: I updated the question, hope it's more clear.